# Why is my view showing multiple rows despite setting multiple values to display in same row?

Tags: views

I am using Drupal 8 and have a simple data model that relates Content types of Children, Parents, and Family. The Family content type aggregates Children and up to 2 Parents with entity relationship fields:

[image: content type relationships]

I am trying to create a view that displays 1 row per child and lists any parent names in the same row. I am able to create a view (with the content type set to children) and configure the family and parent relationships. Then I added the Child's name and the parent(s) entity relationship field to the view. I had (perhaps incorrectly) assumed that the "Multiple field settings" on the parent(s) field would allow me to emit only a single row per child, and list the parents in that row. I configured the field as shown below, checking the "Display all all values in the same row" option:
[image: parent field configuration]

While this does list the parent(s) next to each other in the resulting view, it still duplicates the results for each parent item (see how each child has the child name & parents listed twice):

[image]

Am I misunderstanding what the "Multiple field settings" option is for? Is there something additional I have to do to get a single row per child content item? I see there is a caveat listed by the multiple field settings option that says "be sure to group by EntityID for this setting to have any effect", but have not been able to deduce where this setting is via forum searches. I have tried grouping by the child id with no luck, and would rather not resort to putting a "unique" filter on the query, as this can be computationally expensive and my system will have large numbers of items. Any advice appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: You didn't include enough info about the Parent Relationship to make sense of what's happening. If each parent is a separate node it makes sense to "split" the child node into two rows to list the unique result. The Multivalue field settings work as expected when displaying direct node info. When Relationships are involved it becomes very complex to rely on that setting to control how things are displayed. There is a Setting `Distinct` you may try and see if it helps, I doubt it will. What you probably need is Aggregation, aggregate the Parent field according to Entity or Target ID.

Comment: Correct, each parent is a separate node. Though I assumed that's what multiple field settings was supposed to help with - it does indeed show multiple parents in the same row, I guess I'm a little confused why it wouldn't also prevent duplication, but perhaps it's designed more with taxonomy type fields in mind? I will look at aggregation, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Multiple value settings are a Field structure (on Content Type). Views module is a UI for building database queries, and it's super powerful, but it doesn't cover all angles. Combining data from 2 different database tables is next level complexity in Views, so there can be limitations. One Views is always based on one db table, it's the first thing you choose when creating Views. Aggregation is the way to go, it will look complex but you only need to change one Aggregation setting, the one on the Parent field, all others are grouped.

Comment: Got it, thanks! using aggregation did the trick. Though now I have to contend with the enforced structure of the "Table with aggregation options" display format... it was nice to have the flexible structure of "unformatted list" to rewrite with my own html & patterns.

Comment: I don't think Aggregation controls the Format, you should be able to use Unformatted. Why use the table? Is that one of your Format options?

Comment: The only thing that seems to have the desired effect is to use "Table with aggregation options", then use the "Group Aggregation" setting and set the group function on the child serial ID to "Group and Compress" and then set the group function on the Parent field to "Enumerate". With Unformatted, I tried setting the "Grouping field" to the child serial ID, but it has no effect.